# Unit test consumers in Vertx

Tags: java, unit-testing, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I have a snippet of code that I want to unit test.

```
this.vertx.eventBus().consumer(VERTICLE_ID).toObservable()
        .subscribe(msg -> doSomethingCool());
```

and my consumer method:

```
 private void doSomethingCool(){ 
  // Some cool stuff.
 }
```

Now I want to unit test doSomethingCool() without using powermockito (I want to have code coverage) and I dont want to make my method visible (public). How can I do that? Any hook in vertx to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It actually hard to tell how you should write your test if nothing is known about the purpose of `doSomethingCool`

- Does it return a value? (i.e. via msg.reply())
- Does it modify state of the Verticle? or global state?
- Does it make a downstream call?
- Does your method invoke a handler once it's done with whatever it does?

A unit test should verify an observable result. So write your unit test to verify one of these outcomes. 
In case a handler is invoked, you could work with the vertxunit TestContext and count down an async.

... and stay away from Powermockito.